# Does qemu-monitor-command support external snapshot?

Tags: snapshot, qemu, kvm, libvirt, virsh

I made an external snapshot for 'myvm'. But when I tried to list snapshot info for 'myvm' through `qemu-monitor-command --hmp myvm 'info snapshots'`. There was nothing shown. However, I got correct snapshot info by using `snapshot-list myvm`. I am not clear if qemu-monitor-command support external snapshot?

```
Compiled against library: libvirt 0.10.2
Using library: libvirt 0.10.2
Using API: QEMU 0.10.2
Running hypervisor: QEMU 2.3.0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The 'info snapshots' monitor command you are invoking only reports on qcow2 internal snapshots (ie snapshot data stored inside the original qcow2 file). So if you created external snapshots (using qcow2 backing file feature), this will not be reported via 'info snapshots'.